# NULL Value in my table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a dynamic simple `INSERT`

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Agency (Agency_Id) VALUES (' + CAST(Agency_Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'   
FROM User 
WHERE User_Id = 1
```

But if my `Agency_Id` IS NULL then this query will appear just `NULL` in results and not the query like `INSERT INTO Agency (Agency_Id) VALUES (NULL)`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: **Side note:** Why not use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`: `INSERT INTO Agency (Agency_Id) 
SELECT CAST(Agency_Id AS VARCHAR(10))   
FROM User 
WHERE User_Id = 1`?

Comment: It's because when you concatenate null with anything it will result in NULL.

Comment: If your agency_id is null are you sure you want to be adding a record?

Comment: this is just a sample. The null value can be occurs with another fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Agency (Agency_Id) VALUES (' + ISNULL(CAST(Agency_Id AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NULL') + ')'   
FROM User 
WHERE User_Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'NULL'` for the null values:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Agency (Agency_Id) VALUES (' 
        + ISNULL(Agency_Id,'NULL')
        + ')'   
FROM User 
WHERE User_Id = 1
```